# Parse data with Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I have string that contains this data:

```
<div>
  <a href='https://www.some.html'>
    <img src='https://besttv232.jpg' alt='null' title='null' border='0' width='100' height='56'>
  </a>
</div>
Some text is also over here
```

I need to parse it with Jsoup, I need the a href url, img url and the data (Some text...)

Ive tried with:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myData); //myData is string with content above
Elements links = content.get("div");

for (Element link : links) {
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");
    String linkHrefa = link.attr("img");
    String linkText = link.text();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the a href url

```
Element a = doc.select("a").first();
String src = a.attr("href");
```

> img url

```
Element img = doc.select("img").first();
String src = img.attr("src");
```

> data

```
String content = doc.body().text();
```